# Using a the same variable inside functions outside a function - Dronekit - OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUgc6.png)

How can I use the "red_position" variable that I defined inside the function in the main code?

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please copy and paste your code here as text (in a code block) so that others can more easily help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a global variable outside function and assign its value when the function is called.

Also your function could return values like

`return red_position`

and use like this  `returned_value = colour_detection()`

Comment: using a global isn't nice, can lead to all sorts of problems. Use the return value and the caller stores the result in a local (non-glkobal) variable

Answer (score 0):

you can use the global keyword inside the function like this:

```
red_position = None

def yourfunction():
   your fucntion body 
   if ():
      global red_position # inside a if statement like in your code annd use it whereever you like
```

the varible is inside a if statement so it cannt be accesed outside the function so declare the varible outside the if statement . thats all

Comment: using a global isn't nice, can lead to all sorts of problems. Use the return value and the caller stores the result in a local (non-glkobal) variable